# pass values from ajax success call

Tags: java, ajax

how do i pass the value of ajax success function to my javascript fxn. 
here i want to determine if to submit form or not using the value of "pass" variable 
BUT pass always equal 0 even with x = 60. Why?

```
<form id="stdform" method="post" action="registrtn.php" onsubmit=" return submitForm()">
<input type="text" id ="age" value="30">
<input type ="hidden" id="std" value="STD102"><!--the age for student ID is retrieved frm db using ajax-->
...
<button>submit form </button>
</form>

<script>
function submitForm(){
var ageLimit = document.getElementById("age").value;
var stdid = document.getElementById("std").value ;
var pass = 0;

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'pre-reg.php',
    data:{
       'id':stdid
       },
    success:function(result){
       var x = parseInt(result);
      if (x >= ageLimit) {
           pass = 1;
        }   
      checkvalue(pass);
    }
  });
}
function checkvalue(pass_val){
   if (pass_val==1){
     document.getElementById("stdform").submit();
    }else{
       alert(pass_val);//this shows up=>0, on false condition 
       document.getElementById("errormsg").style.display="block";//this escapes because form already submits
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: your button isn't calling the javascript function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one `function` which will get called when your ajax `success` executed and pass the result to that function to do further process.So,your ajax will look like below :

```
function submitForm() {
  var ageLimit = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var stdid = document.getElementById("std").value;
  var pass = 0;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'pre-reg.php',
    data: {
      'id': stdid
    },
    success: function(result) {
      var x = parseInt(result);
      if (x >= ageLimit) {
        pass = 1;
      }
      check_values(pass); //call function   
    }
  });
}
//pass value
function check_values(pass_val) {
  if (pass_val == 1) {
    //submit form
    document.getElementById('stdform').submit();
  } else {
    alert("something not right")
  }

}
```

Your form :

```
<form id="stdform" method="post" action="registrtn.php">
<input type="text" id ="age" value="30">
<input type ="hidden" id="std" value="STD102"><!--the age for student ID is retrieved frm db using ajax-->
...
<button onclick="submitForm()">submit form </button>
//^^onclick added
</form>
```

Comment: your solution got the logic , but the problem is the form submits even with pass!=1, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you removed `onsubmit` from your form and added onclick to button? Also, does your button have `type="submit"`? If yes please change that to `type="button"`.

Comment: yes i did but the form still submits with condition false.

Comment: When condition is false does `alert` shows up according to my code? Because this code should work if `if (x >= ageLimit)` is right .

Comment: Yes Swati . the alert shows up and still submits the form. That is the most confusing part

Comment: if i return true or false with respect to the condition, it finally looses return value . probably because the check_value function was called by the ajax success function and not the root function submitForm().  pls assist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215438/discussion-between-jay-and-swati).

Comment: i used event.preventDefault(). that solved the problem. i will post the answer just in case someone storms same problem

Comment: Your button has `type="submit"` that's the reason of form submit you need to use `type="button"` as I have already said in comment before.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why pass is 0 is because the ajax call is asynchronous and means that the code that checks the pass variable is evaluated before the request result is returned.Therefore you will need to include the check within the success callback itself for it to work.

However, the pass check is actually unnecessary, since there is only one pass criteria (x > age limit), pass will always equal (x > age limit) so you can just do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'pre-reg.php',
    data:{
       'id':stdid
    },
    success:function(result){
        var x = parseInt(result);

       if (x >= ageLimit) {
           //logic for completing form submission
       }   
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation. i tried Swati solution seems to get me close to my goal, but problem is form submits even when the condition is false. Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="stdform" method="post" action="registrtn.php">
<input type="text" id ="age" value="30">
<input type ="hidden" id="std" value="STD102"><!--the age for student ID is retrieved frm db using ajax-->
...
<button id="submitBtn" type="submit">submit form </button>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener('click',submitForm);
function submitForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();//this line prevents default submission of form
    var ageLimit = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var stdid = document.getElementById("std").value ;
    var pass = 0;

    $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       url: 'pre-reg.php',
       data:{
       'id':stdid
    },
    success:function(result){
       var x = parseInt(result);
       if (x >= ageLimit) {
          pass = 1;
        } 
       checkvalue(pass);  
     }
  });
}
function checkvalue(pass_val){
    if(pass_val == 1){
      document.getElementById("stdform").submit();
    }else{
     alert("something is wrong");
    }
}
</script>
```